# Java generics: cannot convert <X> into <? extends X>

Tags: java, generics

Building the following code with Java 10.0.2+13, Gradle 4.9 & Guava 26.0-jre outputs this error:

Error:

```
argument mismatch; bad return type in method reference

Iterator<Entry<String,ImmutableMap<Path,String>>>

cannot be converted to

Iterator<Entry<? extends String,? extends ImmutableMap<Path,String>>>
```

Code:

```
final Map<String, Map<Path, String>> m = new HashMap<>();

// put entries into m

final ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableMap<Path, String>> im =
    ImmutableMap.<String, ImmutableMap<Path, String>>copyOf(
        m.entrySet().stream().map(
            e -> immutableEntry(
                e.getKey(),
                ImmutableMap.copyOf(e.getValue())
            )
        )::iterator
    )
;
```

Why do `String` & `ImmutableMap<Path,String>` not satisfy `? extends String` & `? extends ImmutableMap<Path,String>`, respectively?

How can I get this to properly compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this does not directly answer your question, but is using a `Collector` not an option?

Like this:

```
ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableMap<Path, String>> im = m.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, e -> ImmutableMap.copyOf(e.getValue())
        ));
```

---

*EDIT*: Just as a *curosity*, this gets your code to compile (but *please* use the `Collector`-version instead, it's **much** more clear than the code below):

```
ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableMap<Path, String>> im = ImmutableMap.copyOf(
        m.entrySet().stream()
                .<Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends ImmutableMap<Path, String>>>map(e -> immutableEntry(e.getKey(), ImmutableMap.copyOf(e.getValue())))
                ::iterator
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works, though I still wonder why `<X>` doesn't satisfy `<? extends X>` without manually inserting the generics before `map(...)`.  It seems like the compiler should be able to infer that.

Comment: It's because of the nested wildcards (`Stream<Map.Entry<?, ?>>`). For example, you can assign `List<String>` to `List<?>`, but you *cannot* assign `List<List<String>>` to `List<List<?>>` (you'd need `List<?>` or `List<? extends List<?>>` to do that). You can [read this](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ104) for a more thorough explanation.